# Mongodb local sharding

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, sharding, horizontal-scaling

I am learning Mongodb and it has been a fun experience so far. Now I am working with around 3-4 collections which have over 6million records each, and I am trying to see if I could horizontal scale that into shards. Just so you all know, I am just trying to learn Mongodb, and the environment that I have is a 64bit - ubuntu system.

I only have one system, so I am trying to understand if I can create shards of the database that I have locally. I honestly do not understand the concept of sharding yet. But I wanted to know if I could create many shards on a single dev system.

I tried looking for resources online, but I haven't found any yet. Any help with this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can if you run all of your shards on different ports and with different db directories.  So you can do

```
mongod --port 27020 --dbpath /var/db/shard1
mongod --port 27021 --dbpath /var/db/shard2 
mongod --port 27022 --dbpath /var/db/shard3
```

and so on.

Then you can connect to your shardsvr instance through `mongos` and enter `sh.addShard( "localhost:27020" )` and so on to add your shards.

Comment: Yes, as long as all members are on different ports you can create a sharded cluster on a single system. Of course, you won't get any performance benefits until you start scaling out to multiple systems.